# How to stop active session automatically when starting debug with the ExtendScript Debug VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: ----------]

When Debug session is running and I press F5 again I get this error message.
Instead I want current session to stop and start again.
What settings I can change to achieve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: what debug extension are you using?

Comment: extendscript-debug

Comment: this one? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Adobe.extendscript-debug because dang- it's closed source and has no issue tracker :|

Comment: yup, that one. I had impression debuggers can be controlled universally by launch.json but I am maybe mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour seems to be specific to the extension you're using ([`Adobe.extendscript-debug`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Adobe.extendscript-debug)) given that the error message is specific to the extension (grep for `config.error.start.session.session.already.running` and `A debug session for host application '{0}' is already active. Please stop the active session before trying again.` and you'll see).

Normally I'd suggest to raise a feature-request issue ticket, but unfortunately, that extension seems to be closed-source and does not seem to have an issue tracker (though I'd be happy to be wrong).

You might just be at a dead end.